# Rails scope - where in exact matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is it possible to make scope in Rails with `where IN (?)` query, which will check exact matches?

for example:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (?)', [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

will find posts with tags `1, 2`, `1, 2, 3` and `1, 2, 3, 4`. But should find only post with `1, 2, 3, 4` tags.

Comment: well, i dont use rails, so is it possible for you to group  posts , aggregating tags to an array and then use array comparison?

Comment: I don't think you even need to do any raw sql there. I think you can just do `Post.joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: tag_ids})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea to get matching all values in `IN` clause you have to do this:

```
tag_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Post.joins(:tags).where('tags.id IN (?)', tags_ids).group("posts.id")
                    .having("COUNT(posts.id) >= ?", tag_ids.length)
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: For me this returns Posts which also have other tag_ids other than [1, 2, 3, 4].  Is there any way to get the exact match, i.e. Posts with only tags having ids 1, 2, and 3?

Answer (score 1):

This should be worked in pgsql database..

```
opp_id = Post.joins(:post_tags).group('post.id').having('ARRAY[?] = ARRAY_AGG(post_tags.tag_id ORDER BY post_tags.tag_id)', tags.sort).pluck(:id)
```