# Rails SQL find all where associations have list ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

**Hey, all!**

Uses Rails 4, Postgresql

How I can find all users which have at least books with id from list

IN, like bellow, not working

Rails

```
list = [1,2,3]
User.includes(:books).where('books.id IN (?)', list)
```

SQL

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
INNER JOIN "books" ON "books"."user_id" = "users"."id"
WHERE "books"."id" IN (1,2,3)
```

I need to find Users who have books 1,2 and 3 necessary.

Thanks

Comment: similar question was asked yesterday [Rails scope - where in exact matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731332/rails-scope-where-in-exact-matches)  , looks like some schools homework meeting deadline? :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks, [LongBeard_Boldy](http://LongBeard_Boldy)

[https://stackoverflow.com/users/5093622/longbeard-boldy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731332/rails-scope-where-in-exact-matches)

It works

EDITED

Add solution:

```
list = [1,2,3]
User.joins(:books).where('books.id IN (?)', list).group('users.id')
  .having("COUNT(users.id) >= ?", list.length)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Also, your links are both incorrect.