# has_and_belongs_to_many exact matches by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using a very standard has_and_belongs_to_many association, like the example in the Rails associations guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

The problem is that I would like to query to find the Assembly with the exact match of parts.  For instance, 
Assembly with 2 Parts associated to it, and the Parts having ids of 1, 2.

Here are my approaches that fail:

```
Assembly.joins(:parts).where(parts: {id: [1,2]})

Assembly.joins(:parts).
  where('parts.id IN (?)', [1,2]).
  group('assemblies.id').
  having('COUNT(assemblies.id) >= ?', [1,2].length)
```

(This one was suggested by this SO answer: [Rails scope - where in exact matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731332/rails-scope-where-in-exact-matches))

These approaches return Assembly objects which just have Parts with ids 1 and 2 included in their associated Parts.  But again, what I want is only Assemblies with exactly those 2 Parts (ids 1 and 2).

Please help!

Comment: @jazzinthermorning, can you say what database are you using?

Comment: Yes, using PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:* Order of elements in PostgreSQL arrays are import. It's possible to use `ORDER BY` inside `ARRAY_AGG` function.

```
Assembly.joins(:parts).
  group('assemblies.id').
  having('ARRAY[?] = ARRAY_AGG(parts.id ORDER BY parts.id)', [1,2].sort)
```

*First version:*

If you are using PostgreSQL, you can do it with [ARRAY_AGG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) group function:

```
Assembly.joins(:parts).
  group('assemblies.id').
  having('ARRAY[?] = ARRAY_AGG(parts.id)', [1,2])
```

Comment: Additionally, using your query, the order matters, which doesn't seem practical.  Any idea of how to match the Assemblies that contain the part ids, regardless of order, i.e. get the same Assembly when passing ids as [1,2] or [2,1]?

Comment: Thank you for that update, I hadn't thought of the order_by and sort, brilliant.

Comment: for people that have id as uuid in postgres,`Assembly.joins(:parts).  group('assemblies.id').having('ARRAY[?] = ARRAY_AGG(parts.id::text ORDER BY parts.id::text)', ['1212-afzaz-12','22412-afzafza-1232'].sort)`